# How to detect @ in angular?

Tags: angular, keyup

Someone know if it's possible to detect a @ in a input in angular ?

I can use :

```
(keyup.enter)="alert()"
```

But I need to do my method for @

Thank you if you have the solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular pseudo-events still have a few shortcomings, especially for symbols and as of now, `@` is one of them. One workaround would be to use `keypress` and check for the `key`.

```html
(keypress)="onPress($event)"
```

```js
onPress(e: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (e.key === '@') {
        // Do something on press of @
    }
}
```

Or

```html
(keypress)="$event.key === '@' ? onPress() : null"
```

```js
onPress(e: KeyboardEvent) {
    // Do something on press of @
}
```